# After Button Click Partial View Shows as Layout null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View and that view consist of 2 partial Views.One partial view has FormSubmit and
when that form submit clicks it needs to go to the next partial view
I have tried it but the problem is Second partial view shows as without layout

### Main View

```
 <div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5" id="cartpartial">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialView1",Model)


        </div>
        <div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5" id="deliverypartial">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialView2",Model)
        </div>
```

### _PartialView1

```
@model XYZ.Domain.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateNewsItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
//Some Code Here
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill btn-lg" value="Next" />
}
```

### _PartialView2

```
@model XYZ.Domain.MyModel
//Some Code Here
```

### Controller Post

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UpdateNewsItem(MyModel model)
 {
  // Some code here
  return PartialView("_PartialView2", model);
 }
```

Comment: You mean when you click submit in PartialView1, it returns a page without layout, right?

Comment: @Tomato32 Yes.. it returns to a PartialView2 with out layout

Comment: I think you can use Jquery for this. If you need, I could post a sample, my friend :))

Comment: @Tomato32 yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend. I'm sorry for the late response. It's my solution. You can refer. Hope to help :))

Main View

```
<div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5" id="cartpartial">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView1", Model);}

</div>
<div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5" id="deliverypartial">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView2", Model);}
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true); //prevent multiple click
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateNewsItem", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',                
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                success: function(result){                    
                    $('#deliverypartial').html(result);
                    $('#cartpartial').hide(); //you can hide partial view 1 if you want
                }
             });
        });
    </script>
}
```

_PartialView 1

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateNewsItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1"}))
{
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Email)
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill btn-lg" value="Next" id="btnSubmit" />
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're implying by "it needs to go to the next partial view" but the reason you don't have the Layout is just because you use the combination of that :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateNewsItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Wich is telling that you want all your page to be updated, and that :

```
return PartialView("_PartialView2", model);
```

Wich is meant to flush your partial content without anything around.

If your need is just to go from the "cart" step to the "delivery", but still having the two in the same view while updating you data. I woul recommand to use the

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateNewsItem", "Home", ...
```

Wich is meant to only update a part of your page.
Be sure to include the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" in your layout (it's available in a NuGet), it won't work without it.

Hope it helps !